# PHP Extension - Segfault With PHP Release Compile

Tags: php, c++, c, segmentation-fault, php-extension

I've written a PHP extension and I have really really weird segfault now.

It's ok if I run the test script by `php test.php` or `php < test.php`, but if I input exactly the same commands in the interactive mode (`php -a`), there will be a segfault.

```
46              char *_class_name = (char *)emalloc(_class_name_len);
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555578f664 in _emalloc ()
```

I firstly thought that there may be some issues with the copy of PHP binaries from Launchpad and I compiled my own one. The configure command was `'./configure'  '--prefix=/opt/php7-dbg' '--with-gd' '--with-mysqli' '--with-readline' '--with-curl'`. (The optimizer argument was `-O2`.)

I got exactly the same issue again, but this time I could go further.

```
46              char *_class_name = (char *)emalloc(_class_name_len);
(gdb) s
_emalloc (size=4) at /home/frederick/Programming/C/php-7.0.6/Zend/zend_alloc.c:2439
2439    {
(gdb) n
2442            if (UNEXPECTED(AG(mm_heap)->use_custom_heap)) {
(gdb) n
2450            return zend_mm_alloc_heap(AG(mm_heap), size ZEND_FILE_LINE_RELAY_CC ZEND_FILE_LINE_ORIG_RELAY_CC);
(gdb) s
zend_mm_alloc_heap (size=4, heap=0x7fffef000040) at /home/frederick/Programming/C/php-7.0.6/Zend/zend_alloc.c:1365
1365            if (size <= ZEND_MM_MAX_SMALL_SIZE) {
(gdb) n
1366                    ptr = zend_mm_alloc_small(heap, size, ZEND_MM_SMALL_SIZE_TO_BIN(size) ZEND_FILE_LINE_RELAY_CC ZEND_FILE_LINE_ORIG_RELAY_CC);
(gdb) s
zend_mm_small_size_to_bin (size=4) at /home/frederick/Programming/C/php-7.0.6/Zend/zend_alloc.c:1211
1211            if (size <= 64) {
(gdb) n
1213                    return (size - !!size) >> 3;
(gdb) s
zend_mm_alloc_heap (size=<optimised out>, heap=0x7fffef000040) at /home/frederick/Programming/C/php-7.0.6/Zend/zend_alloc.c:1366
1366                    ptr = zend_mm_alloc_small(heap, size, ZEND_MM_SMALL_SIZE_TO_BIN(size) ZEND_FILE_LINE_RELAY_CC ZEND_FILE_LINE_ORIG_RELAY_CC);
(gdb) s
zend_mm_alloc_small (bin_num=<optimised out>, size=<optimised out>, heap=0x7fffef000040) at /home/frederick/Programming/C/php-7.0.6/Zend/zend_alloc.c:1286
1286                    size_t size = heap->size + bin_data_size[bin_num];
(gdb) n
1287                    size_t peak = MAX(heap->peak, size);
(gdb) n
1288                    heap->size = size;
(gdb) n
1289                    heap->peak = peak;
(gdb) n
1293            if (EXPECTED(heap->free_slot[bin_num] != NULL)) {
(gdb) n
1295                    heap->free_slot[bin_num] = p->next_free_slot;
(gdb) p bin_num
$1 = <optimised out>
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
zend_mm_alloc_small (bin_num=<optimised out>, size=<optimised out>, heap=0x7fffef000040) at /home/frederick/Programming/C/php-7.0.6/Zend/zend_alloc.c:1295
1295                    heap->free_slot[bin_num] = p->next_free_slot;
```

The corresponding function in my code is:

```
static std::string bnode_object_get_class_name(zval *object) {
    char *ini_ns_key = estrdup("bencode.namespace");
    zend_bool ini_ns = zend_ini_long(ini_ns_key, strlen(ini_ns_key), 0);
    efree(ini_ns_key);
    size_t _class_name_len = ZSTR_LEN(Z_OBJ_P(object)->ce->name);

    // segfault line!
    char *_class_name = (char *)emalloc(_class_name_len);

    strcpy(_class_name, ZSTR_VAL(Z_OBJ_P(object)->ce->name));
    std::string class_name(_class_name);
    efree(_class_name);
    if (ini_ns) {
        return class_name.substr(8);
    } else {
        return class_name;
    }
}
```

I then knew which line produced the segfault and I'd like to solve the problem. So I immediately compiled a debug build of PHP (configure command: `'./configure'  '--prefix=/opt/php7-dbg' '--with-gd' '--with-mysqli' '--with-readline' '--with-curl' '--enable-debug'`, optimizer: `-O0`).

But with the debug build, based on the same codes, the segfault's simply gone!

I'm not a quite experienced C/C++ developer and this is the first time that I've bumped into an issue like this. Please help, thanks a lot.

***UPDATE***

It seems that the problem was caused by a stupid mistake. The line, which caused segfault, should be

```
char *_class_name = (char *)emalloc(_class_name_len + 1);
```

as C strings should be ended with '\0'

But why it's ok with the debug build?

Comment: Interesting. I looked at this for a bit last night and didnt see any egregious errors. Im still not convinced your fix is really addressing the problem. As far as I know, `emalloc` has no idea that it's allocating space for a string and needs space for `'\0'`. The fact that it's seg faulting there is odd. It's been my experience that turning on optimizations exposes problems not seen with optimizations off. My bet is you have some UB in code not shown and for whatever reason it's getting exposed when you call `emalloc`. Are the `zend_` functions yours? What's `zval`? What are the macros?

Comment: @yano Thanks for your reply! Those macros are mostly from PHP, and PHP defines it's own `emalloc` API by `#define emalloc(size) _emalloc((size) ZEND_FILE_LINE_CC ZEND_FILE_LINE_EMPTY_CC)`. What's more, the PHP `emalloc` will behave differently depending on many factors (whether is debugging, or under Windows, or using clang and etc.). It's quite complex and I'm not sure where the problem comes from. Maybe you need the source code of PHP https://secure.php.net/downloads.php#v7.0.6

Comment: eh,, I don't know a thing about `php`. Is this `c++` function you've posted the only `c++` code you're calling, or is this called from other `c/c++` code not posted? Thanks for pointing out that `php` has an `emalloc` function,, I was wondering why your `gdb` step-into `emalloc` looked totally different than the `c` version: http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~ajr/270/a2/soln/emalloc.c

Comment: @yano It's only a segment of the whole extension. FYI, you can find the `emalloc` in PHP from https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_alloc.c line:2400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your program is crashing at `strcpy`, `emalloc` line is just the last one before crash. And there you really have an error and need to add +1 to emalloc because of 0 byte at the end of string.

But you have complicated it too much. Since you are using C++, you can replace all the lines from size_t to efree (including them) with one line:

`std::string class_name(ZSTR_VAL(Z_OBJ_P(object)->ce->name),
        ZSTR_LEN(Z_OBJ_P(object)->ce->name));`

This is also crash-proof.

Also, you complicated the beginning of function:

`char *ini_ns_key = estrdup("bencode.namespace");
zend_bool ini_ns = zend_ini_long(ini_ns_key, strlen(ini_ns_key), 0);
efree(ini_ns_key);`

This should be written this way:

`zend_long ini_ns_long = zend_ini_long("bencode.namespace", strlen("bencode.namespace"), 0);
bool ini_ns=(ini_ns_long!=0);`